# What is the one's complement representation of -120?

Tags: computer-science

Is the right way to do this by first finding the binary representation of 120 and then inverting all the bits?

120 = 1111000

so the one's complement is 111?

Answer (score 0):

120 = ‭111 1000‬
-120 = ‭1000 1000‬

Therefore the one's complement will be : 01110111

After reversing all the bits of -120 i.e ‭1000 1000‬ it becomes 0111 0111 which is the answer in your case.

Comment: How do you konw -120 is 1000 1000?

Comment: using 8 bit notation we can have max -128 to 127. 1000 0000 for -128 and 0111 1111 for 127. using this notation -120 is 1000 1000